# Callback Function

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, callback

I have a method called funct which i want to have as my callback function when i am using the beingreceive socket method in c#.

```
s.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags.None,
               new AsyncCallback(funct), null);
```

The error that am getting is:

> No overload for 'funct' matches delegate 'System.AsyncCallback'

What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"funct" must be a method with the following signature:

```
void funct(IAsyncResult ar) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just use *any* method for your callback.  The function has to have a specific signature (parameter list).

Answer (score 1):

what is the funct? is it a delegate?
if it is, it's signature is not compatibile with AsyncCallback delegate.

funct must be a method looking like this:

```
void SomeMethod(IAsyncResult ar)
```

Answer (score 0):

How does your 'funct' method signature looks like ?

Does it return void ?

Does it have exactly one parameter of type IAsyncResult ?

In other words, does your 'funct' method conform to the [Asynccallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx) delegate ?